# Count result matching in row not all

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the last matching in column 'more' of result VG1.

In this case my query is counting all the results in the column, but I need just to count before its changed. If its VG1, VG1, VG2, VG1 I need result 2, not 3 ( all ).

Query:

```
SELECT home, count(*) as count 
from results 
where more='VG2' and home='pero' 
group by home 
order by count(more) desc
```

[MYSQL schema:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3df67/5/0)

```
CREATE TABLE results
    (`datum` longtext, `home` longtext, `away` longtext, `more` longtext)
;

INSERT INTO results VALUES     ('14.05.2016 ', 'pero', 'miha', 'VG1');
INSERT INTO results VALUES     ('11.04.2016 ', 'pero', 'milan', 'VG1');
INSERT INTO results VALUES     ('10.03.2016 ', 'pero', 'semenka', 'VG2');
INSERT INTO results VALUES     ('24.02.2016 ', 'pero', 'torta', 'VG1');
INSERT INTO results VALUES     ('14.01.2016 ', 'pero', 'miha3', 'VG2');
INSERT INTO results VALUES     ('10.01.2016 ', 'pero', 'simens', 'VG2');
```

Comment: Do you have any PK in the table?

Comment: No. I can add ID but i putting some data from text and its not sorted well, so its not valid result.

Comment: I'm confused. Your question starts by asking for results of VG1. Your query uses VG2. Both sqlfiddle results show 3 not 4

Comment: Yes, when VG2 is there its need to stop count. Its 3 not 4, i written wrong

Comment: Can you edit your post so it says matches what you're trying to ask?

Comment: I just edit, please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use variables for this:

```
select   home, more, count(*) as count 
from     (select   *,
                   @set := if(@home <> home, '', @set),
                   @home := home,
                   not find_in_set(more, @set) as is_first,
                   @set := if (@more <> '' and @more <> more, 
                               concat(@set, @more, ','), 
                               @set),
                   @more := more
          from     results,
                   (select @set:='', @prev:='', @home='') init
          order by home, datum desc) base
where is_first
group by home, more 
order by count(*) desc
```

Output:

```
| home | more | count |
|------|------|-------|
| pero |  VG1 |     2 |
| pero |  VG2 |     1 |
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc9a6/1)

The `is_first` column from the inner query indicates whether a record belongs to the first bunch of `more` values per `home`. This is put as a condition in the outer query, so that the `count` function returns the required result.

If you need only the result for a certain `home` and `more` value, then just add that in a `where` clause in the outer query.

Comment: This helps me a lot, but im worry about my website if i have a lot of this queries is it going to slow him?

Comment: This query will not run as fast as a query that does not need a sub query. So if you need to tune performance, I would suggest to extend your table with an additional `is_first` flag that you should keep updated with a function. It will cost you slight performance on updates, but give you a slight boost on queries.